# Socket.io with Outlook Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, socket.io

I'm trying to use SocketIoClientDotNet library with my Outlook Add-In but I'm failing to connect the socket. this is my code:

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost");
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
    socket.Emit("hi");
    socket.On("hi", (data) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        socket.Disconnect();
    });
});
Console.ReadLine();
```

Weird thing is that if I run this code in a new console application project, it works, but when I go back to my Outlook Add-In project and try to run it in the `ThisAddIn_Startup()` event, it fails. Both projects target .NET 4.0 client profile and they use the same local server with socket.io 1.4.28. Is there something I'm missing about Microsoft Add-Ins??

Comment: What do you mean `it fails`?  Which line of code is failing and what is the exact error message.

Comment: Nothing happens in the server and it triggers the `Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR` in the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the full edition of .Net framework as a target framework for the add-in.

Also I'd recommend running another thread for a long-runnning tasks such as IO. The fact is that Outlook may disable add-ins if they take a lot of time to start. The [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling) section from the *What's new in Outlook 2013* article in MSDN states the following:

> Extending the add-in resiliency pillar of Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.
>
> For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold

The Startup method shouldn't take more than 1000 milliseconds.